# Find max element in each column in a 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, max, min

For finding max element in i th row in a 2-D matrix[n][m], this is working

```
    int t= *max_element(matrix[i],matrix[i]+m);
```

but I am not getting how to find max element in i th column in the same way.

Comment: It seems like that the matrix is stored in a row-major format, i.e. `martix[i]` returns the `i`-th row. So you would have to intruduce a stride which is the width of the matrix and look for the max. element

Comment: Also it would be very helpful to provide some example code to verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) works for rows is quite simple: the algorithm accepts *forward iterators* to specify a range, so one might pass pointers as well: a pointer points to the first element in the row and a pointer points behind the last one. The elements in the row form a continuous block in memory, so the approach with pointers works well.

On the other hand, there is no way to use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) for column elements in the same way as column elements do not form a continuous block in memory.

The most natural way will be just to write a simple cycle and do not use STL algorithms.